# /usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file when trying to run a Docker-related script

Tags: bash, docker

I recently migrated from Mac Os to Linux Pop Os and I'm currentyl lost as to how to manage the Docker image resources on Linux. I saw the commands:

```
docker run -m=whatever [container]
```

But they currently are not working with error

```
/usr/bin/bash: /usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
```

Are there any options similar to Docker Desktop on Mac Os where I can manage containers resources on a GUI?
The image I'm working with is [alidock](https://github.com/alidock/alidock) installed via their install.sh

```
bash <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alidock/alidock/master/alidock-installer.sh)
```

Thanks to anyone that helps!

Comment: Seems your problem is more related with the bash error rather than Docker

Comment: The installation is fresh, I literally just did sudo apt install docker

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 17:44 /bin/bash


and 

/usr/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=a6cb40078351e05121d46daa768e271846d5cc54, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

Comment: Should be 64-bit, where can I check?

Comment: ``lscpu`` second line

Comment: nrubini@pop-os:~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit

Comment: Can you try ``docker run hello-world`` and see if that works?

Comment: The image works fine, I'm currently installing new packages on it (it checks with hello-world every time it launches)

Comment: It is not meant to install stuff. Start from ``alpine:latest`` or ``ubuntu:latest``

Comment: This often happens when your `ENTRYPOINT` is `/bin/bash` and your `CMD` is also `/bin/bash`, leading to effectively `/bin/bash /bin/bash` (or similarly with `sh`) where you are basically passing the Bash binary to Bash as if it were a script file.

Comment: Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]